# forEach failure at undefined array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, undefined-behavior

For a very long time I used

```
for (var n in nodes) {f(nodes[n])}
```

quite successfully. But, switching to the neat

```
nodes.forEach(f)
```

I have noticed that it fails at undefined nodes, whareas `for-in` loop did not. I wonder, how can I make forEach to operate identically?

Comment: Can you explain how it *fails*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't. Because `.forEach` is just a function, and you can't call a function on `null`/`undefined`. What you could do is:

```
(arr || []).forEach(f);
```

But for these cases I recommend to use the `for of` loop or the regular `for` loop, which are both identical to `.forEach`. `for in` has a different semantic.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `for(;;)` loop **or** test for the existence of `undefined` first.

You shouldn't have been using the `for ( in )` for iterating over array-like objects. You should have used a `for(;;)` loop or used a standard array looping function with the object as its context (e.g. `Array.protoype.forEach.call(arrayLikeObject, fn)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check before with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
Array.isArray(nodes) && nodes.forEach(cb);
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be cleaner to add `if (typeof nodes !== 'undefined')`

Comment: doesn't answer the question

Comment: Well Lux already answered that you can't call a function on null/undefined, so this solves the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't the `typeof` say `object`, not `nodes`?